# open vscode reference with keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I hover the [mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmvgA.png) over a function or variable, the code shows me a short help (information). I don't like to use a mouse when writing code. How can I open this help with a hotkey?